# How to fetch number of copied rows of Copy Data in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have "Copy Data" (and "Lookup") activity doing select and insert to table1 to table2.

Is it possible to fetch simple way how many row (like 322 rows) was inserted without creating of "Lookup" with SQL Select count?

Comment: Have you tried any specific approach to solve the problem? If so, please provide additional details about them.

Comment: Hey, just to be clear you are copying data from table 1 to table 2 correct? If yes why use look up activity in your flow nad not just copy activity

Comment: you can use lookup.output.count ->which will gives the number of resultant rows,i dont think any other easy methods

Comment: You can simply get it from `Details` after running the pipeline like below format.
**"rowsRead": 6,**
**"rowsCopied": 6,**